# Mdadm seems to have completely forgotten about a device and shrunk my array

Tags: server, raid, mdadm

After a bit of investigating of a problem I've just encountered, it looks like mdadm has completely forgotten about a new device I'd added to an array. I recently added a new device to the array which went fine, but I've now rebooted (I don't think I had rebooted since making this change) and I've been greeted with all sorts of errors, and I'm fairly sure it's down to this.

So my question is: Should it be safe to just re-add that device back into the array? I *really* don't want to lose any data here! This is what I *think* I should do but I'd like confirmation from someone with a bit more experience first :) Bear in mind I've already done this once, and have fscked and grown the filesystem too, and have then written plenty more data to it.

```
sudo umount /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd1
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=4
```

---

A bunch of extra information and steps I've already taken: I rebooted and was greeted with a message along the lines of "Unable to read superblock" for /dev/md0, my RAID array. I immediately suspected mdadm since I had recently been fiddling with it, and `cat /proc/mdstat` reports this:

```
...
md0 : inactive sdb1[0](S) sdc1[1](S)[/code]
```

Which is wrong; I had just added /dev/sdd1 to the array too. `sudo mount -a` reported `bad superblock on /dev/md0`. I can't remember the next command I used now but something else reported that I had tried to write past the end of the filesystem, which makes sense since there was more data on it than could fit onto the first two devices alone.

`sudo fdisk -l` reports that the new device and partition are alive and well. `cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` shows this:

```
DEVICE /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=2 UUID=*snip*
spares=1
```

Which shows clearly that it's completely forgotten about the new device I added. Was I supposed to 'save' the config after executing the commands above? I assumed they were lasting changes; I can't see any use in them being lost on restarting.

Edit note: I realised that the 'num-devices=2' is inclusive of the 'spares=1', which means that mdadm hasn't changed a disk from 'in use' to 'spare', it's just plain forgotten about it. I'll update the title to account for that.

Comment: Did you check in syslog why the device got kicked out of the array?

Comment: (But maybe check out my answer first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
DEVICE /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

means that mdadm will only check those 2 devices to be used as part of a RAID array.

You need to add `/dev/sdd1` to that line, or replace it with:

```
DEVICE partitions
```

which is the default and will make it scan **all** partitions for mdadm superblocks.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! The array is back exactly as I thought I had left it. I guess the commands issued to mdadm don't survive a reboot is all that has happened here - in future I'll update mdadm.conf instead.

Comment: The commands certainly don't survive a reboot, but they store all necessary information in the "superblock".  Of course, if during boot not all devices are searched for superblocks, some parts of your RAID might not get found...  I suggest you use the `DEVICE partitions` option; it will probably slow down your boot with a couple of milliseconds, but you won't have to think about updating that line anymore.  ;-)

Comment: I think that's what I had a while ago, but it caused some odd problems that I've seen some other people having where it renames devices. Now that I know about this I shan't forget in future :) Thanks again for the advice!